# How to get Edge to recognize keyboard events after reload?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In my web-page I have set up a few keydown -handlers for different keys like arrow-left etc.

They work when I enter my url to the location field on Edge, also on FireFox and Chrome.

But if I click the Refresh/reload -button on Edge the keydown -handler stops responding UNTIL I click on the the window. FireFox and Chrome do not have this problem.

So I thought the problem could be that refresh loses the focus from the main browser window and maybe therefore Edge does not get the key-presses after reload.

So I tried in my onload -handler setting

```
 document.body.focus();
```

But that does not fix the problem.
Is there a way to get Edge to recognize key presses after reload/refresh -button has been clicked?

Is there perhaps a way I could programmatically 
cause the onclick event 
in the main window from my onload -handler? That might
get around the problem, who knows.

Here's some code I tried in my onload-handler
trying to get the focus to the main window but
it just doesn't compute:

```
window.focus();
setTimeout
( () =>
  { // window.focus()
    document.body.focus()
  }
, 222
);
```

I tried several things like putting the focus on the window, document, and body. And using a timeout and not. I can verify by using the debugger that the above code in the onload -handler does get executed when the refresh is clicked. It just doesn't seem to have any effect, until I click the main window.

Comment: Please show the code and where you execute it. For example some browsers treat onload after a refresh differently and need code before the `</body>` tag instead of in an onload handler

Comment: I have verified that the onload-handler does get called on Edge when I click reload. In the onload-handler I do  window.addEventListener
('keydown', keyPressHandler ) .  If  I put focus in the location field and click enter everything works on the page. It is only when I do refresh on Edge that key-presses dont work until I click on the  page.  And everything works on FireFox and Chrome. So I guess my question is why and how Edge refresh button works differently from FireFox and Chrome?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution to this issue.  Typical Microsoft.

Comment: Some additional info:  It works if I open a new Edge-window and enter the URL there.